# grizzly exception Illegal attempt to exceed the configured maximum number of headers: 100

Tags: glassfish, grizzly, glassfish-5

After migrating from glassfish 4.1.2 to glassfish 5 in our project, grizzly is throwing the following exception:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders$MaxHeaderCountExceededException: Illegal attempt to exceed the configured maximum number of headers: 100
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders.createHeader(MimeHeaders.java:466)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders.addValue(MimeHeaders.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPushBuilder.<init>(ApplicationPushBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.newPushBuilder(Request.java:2609)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.newPushBuilder(RequestFacade.java:1167)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.newPushBuilder(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:425)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getPushBuilder(ExternalContextImpl.java:728)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.pushIfPossibleAndNecessary(ExternalContextImpl.java:701)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.encodeResourceURL(ExternalContextImpl.java:662)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ResourceELResolver.getValue(ResourceELResolver.java:143)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:208)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:139)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.evaluateExpressionIntoBuffer(ResourceHelper.java:832)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.readExpressionIntoBufferAndEvaluateIntoBuffer(ResourceHelper.java:755)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.read(ResourceHelper.java:719)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:345)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:87)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:667)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2Session.sendMessageUpstream(Http2Session.java:1309)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2Session.sendMessageUpstream(Http2Session.java:1285)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ServerFilter$2.run(Http2ServerFilter.java:1033)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried the following commands to change maximum headers on running server-config:

```
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.max-request-headers=1000
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.http.max-request-headers=1000

asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.max-response-headers=1000
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.http.max-response-headers=1000
```

But with no luck. Still grizzly throwing exception Illegal attempt to exceed the configured maximum number of headers: **100**

How to fix the problem?

Comment: did you ever find how to solve this issue?

Comment: we are now testing payara server instead)

Comment: I've had the same result in payara 5 as well. I had to disable http2 as a workaround for this to work

Answer (score 0):

- start glassfish
- bring up the admin console
- navigate to Configuration->HTTP Service->HTTP Listeners->http-listener-1->HTTP
- set Send Buffer Size and Header Buffer Length
- restart glassfish